# How to make one css input type be displayed the same as another input type

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I'm using a special input type for the iPhone mobile safari browser:

```
<li><textarea placeholder="Store Description" ></textarea></li>
<li><input class="input['text']" type="tel" name="name" placeholder="Store Phone Number" id="some_name" /></li>
```

The problem is that the framework I'm using has CSS styles associated with inputs that have `type="text"`. When I switch to `type="tel"` it displays incorrectly. I would like to make the input use the same class without considering the *type of input*. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, select both input types:

```
input[type=text], input[type=tel]{ //CSS style in here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to copy the CSS for  input['text'] and put it in a class of your own. Then you need to apply that class to your textbox. Keep in mind about targeting the style. Most probably your style will need to be targeted with an extra selector to override the styles defined for the input['text']

CSS targeting : http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Comment: I see - that definitely works. But I'm still curious though  (just for knowledges sake) if it is possible in CSS to do what I am saying. I.e assign all div elements the same css class as all span elements by setting  the class property (not modifying the css). I'm guessing the answer is no.

Comment: Depends on how your css is written. if your CSS is specifically targeted for SPANs then no (span.class), if it's not targeted (.class) simply applying the class will do.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't modify the css?

`input[type="text"], input[type="tel"] { /* style */ }`